# Get unique event identifier by cloud scheduler

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

I am using the GCP cloud scheduler that pushes a message in the the pubsub which triggers a cloud function.

The Cloud scheduler ensures at least single delivery but I want to ensure that the cloud function doesn't get triggered again. So I want to check that whether an event is repeated for the first time by checking an identifier in a data store.

What property I can check of the message which will be unique even if the cloud scheduler gets triggered multiple times?

Will the eventId in the context object be unique for a scheduled event or anything else, which I can use to check if it's a first-time event or a repeated triggered event?

Comment: Do you want dynamic value generation with Cloud Scheduler?

Comment: Not really, I want to how to identify a single scheduled trigger. For e.g.
if the scheduler triggers at 11:00 AM, and my cloud function crashes and retries with the same pubsub message, this message should have some kind of unique identifier for scheduler's trigger.

Also if the scheduler triggers messages twice by mistake, then the cloud function should be able to know that only a single event is triggered, but two messages are sent.

In other words, the cloud function should run only once for a single trigger.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere
Also is it possible to get the date time when the event was scheduled?

Comment: you only have the metadata data of the message. Each PubSub message has a single ID (for the same Topic) and has a creation date. You might have a look to the attribute, you should have more info

Comment: what if the scheduler triggers pubsub event twice for a schedule, there will be two messages having different IDs, and in the cloud function, I won't be able to know that they are for the same event scheduled trigger.

In the attribute also, what could be the unique identifier for the scheduler as the scheduler doesn't give anything which can be used in payload to pubsub

Comment: A scheduler publish only 1 message.

Comment: The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler) says:
Enterprise-grade reliability for cron jobs. Guaranteed at least once delivery to your job targets.

So can't it publish multiple messages? If there's a 100% guarantee, that it will publish only a single message then there is no problem and I don't need any identifier as it will be unique for one schedule.

Comment: It's true. When a cron job run, it triggers an HTTP endpoint and wait for a valid HTTP code (2XX). However, because network issues can happens, if nothing it received, a new call is performed. With external or user managed endpoint, it can happen sometimes, with PubSub, a very high available service on Google Cloud, it should be exceptional!!

Comment: okay, so you're saying, if the scheduler is able to send a message to the pubsub, then it won't retry again, so each event will be unique for each schedule.
So in simple, the scheduler will give only a single message in the pubsub, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right